# Task Scheduler is not executing Start-Sleep in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, sleep, scheduled-tasks

I have a file called XLStoXLSX.ps1 which I am running it using a (.bat) file from Task scheduler as below :

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "E:\Conversion XLS to XLSX\XLStoXLSX.ps1"  1>E:\Conversion XLS to XLSX\logs\Logs.log 2>&1
```

which will work fine if I ran it outside the task scheduler, this the content of XLStoXLSX.ps1

```
$folderpath         = "E:\One drive\HAJJAJ\SFTP\data\02_Hour\"
$ConversionFolder   = "E:\One drive\HAJJAJ\Conversion_Space\02_Hour\"
$ProductionFolder   = "E:\One drive\HAJJAJ\SFTP\data\02_Hour\"

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook
write-host $xlFixedFormat
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true  
$filetype ="*xls"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include $filetype -recurse | 
ForEach-Object `
{
    $path = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
    $pathBackup = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("\"))
    $FileNameToMove = $path.Replace($folderpath,$ConversionFolder)
    $FileNameBackUp = $pathBackup.Replace($folderpath,$ConversionFolder)+"\Done\" 
    $ProductionFileNameToMove = $path.Replace($folderpath,$ProductionFolder)
    $ProductionFileNameBackUp = $pathBackup.Replace($folderpath,$ProductionFolder)+"\Done\"
   
    "Converting $path"
    $FileNameBackUp += $(get-date -f yyyyMMddHHmmss) +  ($_.Name -replace '\.xls', '.xlsx')
    $ProductionFileNameBackUp  += $(get-date -f yyyyMMddHHmmss) +  ($_.Name -replace '\.xls', '.xlsx')

    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)
    

    if($_.length/1MB -gt 50MB) {  Start-Sleep -Seconds 400 }else { Start-Sleep -Seconds 20 }
 
    $FileNameToMove += ".xlsx"
    $ProductionFileNameToMove += ".xlsx"
    #moving file to backup file on Conversion_Space before  Conversion
    Move-Item   -Path $FileNameToMove  -Destination  $FileNameBackUp

    $workbook.saveas($FileNameToMove, $xlFixedFormat) 
    $workbook.close()

    
    if($_.length/1MB -gt 50MB)
    { Start-Sleep -Seconds 50 }else { Start-Sleep -Seconds 20 }
    $oldFolder = $path.substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf("\")) 
    
    write-host $oldFolder
    if(-not (test-path $oldFolder))
    {
        new-item $oldFolder -type directory
    }
    
    move-item $_.fullname $oldFolder

    #moving file to backup file on Conversion_Space before  Conversion
    Move-Item   -Path $ProductionFileNameToMove  -Destination  $ProductionFileNameBackUp
    Move-Item   -Path $FileNameToMove  -Destination  $ProductionFileNameToMove
    #moving the file to Production 
    
}
$excel.Quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
```

, the code will be executed but it will not execute this part of code :

```
if($_.length/1MB -gt 50MB) {  Start-Sleep -Seconds 400 }else { Start-Sleep -Seconds 20 }
```

any suggestion to solve this issue, or is their a better way to give some time for the excel file to be open?

Comment: Is drive E: a network drive?  If so, check your account context in which the scheduled task runs, and ensure any account that maps that drive is logged-in when the scheduled task runs.   Also, `$excel.visible = $true` may require the account to have interactive logon rights.

Comment: I sat it to false and still the same issue, E: is local drive

Comment: Hopefully "One drive" is a local folder and not Microsoft's OneDrive cloud storage.  Anyhow, short of binding to Excel's Open and Activate event handlers, how about calling `$excel.ScreenUpdating = $false` then `$workbook.Activate()` and `$workbook.RefreshAll()` ?  Optionally, you could also try `$excel.Wait((get-date -Date ((get-date).AddSeconds(400)) -Format 'hh:mm:ss'))`; but may cause other side-effects.